# Why does TSQL not ignore trailing spaces of identifiers when used with a linked server?

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, trailing-whitespace

I have a query on a database table like this `select * from dbo.MyTable` which works fine even though for reason I don't know the table `MyTable`    has been created with trailing spaces in the identifier.

That should not let me worry as described [here](https://michaeljswart.com/2014/09/sql-server-ignores-trailing-spaces-in-identifiers/) since SQL Server just ignores trailing spaces. Unfortunately, I have a case where I need to select the data from that table using a linked server like this:

```
select * 
from linkedserver.targetdb.dbo.[MyTable   ]
```

I need to use the quotename including the spaces otherwise I get the error:

> An invalid schema or catalog was specified for the provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "linkedserver"

Unfortunately the queries are generated dynamically and don't account for the trailing space as a comparison of the object name with the `information_schema` table works (correctly ignoring the trailing spaces).

Could this be related to the provider SQLNCLI11 or a configuration of the linked server?

Comment: Why not just remove the trailing spaces from the table name? Seems like a much simpler, and cleaner approach rather than trying to debug the internals of cross server name resolution.

Comment: Fixing the table's name seems to be the solution here.

Comment: Fixing the table name is definitely what I will discuss. It is not my object and I want to be sure that I've looked at the problem from a few perspectives. I don't know if there's some other code using selects on that table via the mentioned linked server. Changing the name might break it.

Answer (score 3):

Considering that, as you stated, SQL Server is "happy" to reference a table called `MyTable`    as `MyTable`, apart from when you used a linked server query, the obvious solution is to fix the name of the table.

You can do this using `sp_rename`. For example:

```sql
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.[YourTable   ] (SomeCol int);
GO

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(100) = N'SELECT * FROM dbo.YourTable;'; --Just to prove the same statement is run

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;

SELECT DATALENGTH([name]) --returns 20, so spaces are tehre
FROM sys.tables 
WHERE [name] LIKE N'MyTabl%';

EXEC sys.sp_rename N'dbo.YourTable   ',N'YourTable';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;

SELECT DATALENGTH([name]) --Returns 14, so spaces are gone.
FROM sys.tables 
WHERE [name] LIKE N'MyTabl%';
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

Additional note: if you do have some code that references the object as `dbo.[YourTable   ]` it will still work if the trailing spaces from the table's actual name are removed as well.

Comment: Perhaps your table is already being used in several other places and you cannot rename it, so you can create `SYNONYM` https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/statements/create-synonym-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @EliseuMarcos notice my comments about how trailing spaces are handled by the database.